# Get size of returned data table in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery file that uses the data function to request data from a PHP page.
The PHP page returns a HTML table. I have this used as a popup, but I want to dynamically change the size of the popup so that the HTML table fits.

How do I go about this? I've given the returned table a class of 'status' and am trying to get the width and height of status, but have realised that this probably will give the CSS properties, and not the actual height.

```
  $(popElement).css({left:leftVal,top:topVal})
    .html("<div id='loading'></div>").load(url);
  var divHeight = $("table.status").width(); //this is the returned table
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `.width` works just fine for measuring an element. Really; try it. Or you could look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/).